# How do I log/aggregate data from Firebug's Net panel?

Tags: firefox, firebug, logging, aggregate

So basically I want to know how I can log data from Firebug's Net panel. More specifically, I want to be able to log each time e.g. 'load' (event)
I know that I am able to use the Persist function in the Net tab itself. But that is not enough. I can't click through each request writing down the times. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the [***NetExport***, Firebug extension](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/)?